# Filter orders by specific product sku

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, catalog

I need to get order collection, Those orders have a specific product sku,
Like I have a series of sku's "NT", So get all orders which are starting with "NT"

```
$SKU = NP;
$orders = array();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => $SKU))
    ->load();
foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
  echo $orderItem->getOrder();
}
```

Comment: Please add your code which you have tried

Comment: Please find above code that i tried.

Comment: also add what error you are facing with your current approach.

Comment: Blank page is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to filter the orders based on product sku,

```
 $sku = "NP";
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->join(array('order_item' => 'sales/order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id');

 $orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.sku', array(array('like' => '%'.$sku.'%')));
```

Comment: using this i'm not able to print specific name or date

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. but you can't echo Order Object.
Try echo `$orderItem->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();` or `$orderItem->getOrder()->getId();`

Also update your `$sku` to add `quotes` like `$SKU = 'NP';` And make sure You have a product with sku including 'NP'