# Magento 1 remove item from order

Tags: magento-1.9

Below is the code which i am using right now, but it not working.

```
  <?php
    define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/.."));
    require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::init();
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('global');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from'     => strtotime('-1 day', time()),
            'to'       => time(),
            'datetime' => true,
        ))->load();
    $orders_to_check = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $order_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            echo $item->getSku();
            if($item->getSku() == 'S343697'){
               $item->delete();
               $orders->save();
            } 
        }
    }
    print_r($orders_to_check);exit;
```

any thoughts how to remove item from order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code and check if it helps! I have also added the code to remove the item price from the order total as well.

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/.."));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->addEventArea('global');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from'     => strtotime('-1 day', time()),
    'to'       => time(),
    'datetime' => true,
));

//return count($orders);
//return count($orders->getData());

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order_id = $order->getRealOrderId();

    $base_grand_total = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $base_subtotal = $order->getBaseSubtotal();
    $grand_total = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
    $tax_amount = $order->getTaxAmount();
    $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
    $subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getSubtotalInclTax();
    $total_item_count = $order->getTotalItemCount();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        //echo $item->getSku();
        if($item->getSku() == 'S343697'){
            
            $item_price = $item->getPrice();
            $item_tax_amount = $item->getTaxAmount();
            $item->delete();
 
            //remove item price from Order price and update the Order totals.
            $order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total-$item_price);
            $order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal-$item_price);
                $order->setGrandTotal($grand_total-$item_price);
            $order->setSubtotal($subtotal-$item_price);
            $order->setTaxAmount($tax_amount-$item_tax_amount);
            $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
            $order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
            $order->setTotalItemCount($total_item_count-1);

            $orders->save();
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Bhaumik, let me check above ansewer. Any thoughts on this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320694/how-to-filter-orders-by-sku-magento-1

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal Check this ans: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160286