# How to filter orders by sku Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

i am trying to filter orders that have sku in its item collection
I am not sure if we can use filters directly for product attributes on order collection using function.

is their any way to do so ?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160286

Comment: If above not help then look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018513

Comment: Thanks @BhaumikUpadhyay the answer that used query, its not the ideal one as it can cause performance issue for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orderItem->getSelect()
    ->joinInner(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id')
    ->where('product_id=?', 'anysku')
    ->order('main_table.order_id DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to filter the orders based on product SKU,

```
$sku = "YOUR SKU NAME HERE";
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->join(array('order_item' => 'sales/order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id');

 $orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.sku', array(array('like' => '%'.$sku.'%')));
```

Let me know if it's help you...!! Thank You

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, what does "$orders" returns ?