# How to get all orders with a specific SKU using the REST API?

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I’m trying to figure out if a product was bought and when, but other than looping over all orders I don’t see how I can do that.

I saw [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/160279/92968) but I need to do it through the REST API.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

1. Use the [`orders/items`](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/ordersitems/#operation/GetV1OrdersItems) endpoint using a filter on the SKU
2. If the information is not sufficient, use the `order_id` key of each item to get the order with the [`order/{id}`](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/ordersid/#operation/GetV1OrdersId) endpoint